# How do I replace v-data-table pagination with v-pagination

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to replace the default table pagination with the `v-pagination` which allows one to pick a particular page instead of clicking next and next endlessly.

Currently the `v-data-table` comes with this:

[image: 1]

But I want to replace it with:

[image: 2]

Keep in mind that I want to still keep the items per page section.